# Cómo definir a qué dispositivo se va a a conectar vía Bluetooth

Tags: android

Estoy desarrollando un juego el cual funciona mediante Bluetooth, pero he estado leyendo la página Android Developers cómo hacer conexiones Bluetooht, pero quiero saber cómo se define a qué dispositivo se va a conectar vía Bluetooth. En pocas palabras, ¿cómo específico a qué dispositivo me voy a conectar?, busco un ejemplo de código que me puedan proporcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Para esto necesitas primero listar los dispositivos que se hay cercanos a tu android, lo puedes hacer mediante el siguiente código:

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
for(BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices)
   s.add(bt.getName());

setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list, s));
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10795529/6371926

Luego tendrías que conectarte de la siguiente forma:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18397935/6371926